# Openstack - VNC console of an instance stuck in "connecting" mode

Tags: openstack, vnc, openstack-neutron, openstack-horizon

newbie here!

I have 3 physical machines with Openstack Yoga installed and running (a controller, a compute and a block storage node).

These 3 machines are physically connected (through Ethernet cable) to a router inside the same LAN (with for example addresses 192.168.x.y) , so I don't have a management and a provider network, but a self-hosted network.

All installations went good, I am able to create instances and all works correctly, except for the vnc console.

When I try to access to the online console of an instance through the Horizon dashboard it gets stuck in "Connecting" mode and it never connects. I've followed the official Openstack Yoga documentation and looked through all the possible log files of every openstack component I have installed but there is no warning or error to understand why I can't access the console.

Also I can ping or ssh into my instance, so it isn't a network related problem.

These are my /etc/nova/nova.conf configuration files:

**CONTROLLER NODE:**

```
[DEFAULT]
my_ip = 192.x.x.x (controller's node IP)

[vnc]
enabled = true
server_listen = $my_ip
server_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
```

**COMPUTE NODE:**

```
[DEFAULT]
my_ip = 192.x.x.x (controller's node IP)

[vnc]
enabled = true
server_listen = 0.0.0.0
server_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
novncproxy_base_url = http://controller:6080/vnc_auto.html
```

Any hint/suggestion on what to search for or how to resolve?

Comment: Is the openstack-nova-novncproxy.service up and running? Can you share your nova.conf from a compute node, especially the [vnc] section? Please update your question and use appropriate code tags.

Comment: Hi @eblock, thanks for your reply. Yes, the novncproxy service is up and running. I've edited my question and add my conf files as you suggest me.

Comment: I think you can remove the entries from the controller's nova.conf, but they probably don't hurt either. Is "controller" resolving to the correct address? Maybe use FQDN instead (or the IP)?

Comment: I've just removed the entries but the situation hasn't changed. It is still stuck in connecting mode. I've also changed the "controller" hostname to its actual IP.

Comment: What does the logfile tell you? /var/log/nova/nova-novncproxy.log (the actual file location and name depends on your distro and deployment)

Comment: Nothing useful, just a Timeout Error after about 5 minutes remaining stuck in connecting mode

Comment: Could you enable debug logs, restart the service and try again?